# Detect when AngularFire2 storage upload is done

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular6

I am migrating a site from Angular 4 stack to new Angular 6 and AngularFire 2 stack.   It seems there have been a few changes in AngularFire 2 methods.

I have the following code:

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.child('sitemap.xml').put(sitemapBlob, metaData);
```

I would like to detect when the upload is complete and it appears the `.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED` functionality I had used in the old version is no longer there.

How do I detect when the upload is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

I create a sample app that uploads a file to Firestorage and return the current download URL. Take a look:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firestorage-test-r2sjvz

---

The proper way to check if your upload is completed is using:

```
// get notified when the download URL is available
uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

and your html:

```
<a [href]="downloadURL | async">{{ downloadURL | async }}</a>
```

Refer to oficial documentation for a complete example: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#monitoring-upload-percentage

Comment: See my response on May 7th below:  "Tried that, and get an error of Property snapshotChanges() does not exist on type 'UploadTask' "

Comment: Do you have a variable called uploadTask? This error occurs only if not. What Angularfire version did you using?

Comment: This is my code `const fileRef = storage.ref().child('sitemap.xml');
  const uploadTask = fileRef.put(sitemapBlob, metaData);   
  this.uploadPercent = uploadTask.percentageChanges();
  uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
   finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL()),
   console.log(this.downloadURL)
  )`   And I am using "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"

Comment: I create a sample app on Stackblitz to explain how to make it works with Angularfire2 and Firestorage. Take a look at my answer above. Your code is mixing FirebaseSDK and Angularfire, they are similar but don't have the same syntax. If my reply was util, please, mark the check to make it the solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md) you should be able to do something like this:

```
const uploadTask = storageRef.child('sitemap.xml').put(sitemapBlob, metaData);    

uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  filter(task => task.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS)
).subscribe(() => {
  // upload successful
});
```

Comment: Tried that, and get an error of *Property snapshotChanges() does not exist on type 'UploadTask'*